# How can I convert the number of particles per liter to gram per liter

Tags: concentration

How can I convert the number of particles per liter to gram per liter? I know the size of these particle and so, I calculated the volume and then by the density I calculate the mass. After that I don't know what to do

Comment: Do you know which substance this is or only how many particles per liter are in your solution?

Comment: I am not sure about the substances. Because I am still investigating that. They are about 8e8 particles per ml

Answer (score 1):

$$x \frac{particles}{L} \times \frac {1 mol}{6.023 \times 10^{23}particles}\times \frac{MW gm}{mol}$$

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the Avogadro constant -> calculate how many moles per liter there are in your mixture and then, using the molecular mass, you can calculate the concetration in g/L. That is if you know your compound.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not certain what these particles are!! So it is hard to assume molecular mass